# i can't add objects to an arrayList

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-asynctask

i'm trying to download a list of cases from a server and then populate an arraylist to use it in my RecyclerView Adapter but every time i try to populate the array list from asynctask i can print the data in every single step from the populating bu not from the Arraylist i'm using (i'm trying to store in an arrayList that contains objects of the type Case which i created)

this is the part of the code with the problem 
                          this is my AsyncTask...
`

```
 public class downloadingNewCases extends AsyncTask<Void,Void ,Boolean>{
        private String userid ;
        private String state ;
        public downloadingNewCases(String userid ,String state ){
            this.userid = userid ;
            this.state = state ;
        }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.d(AppController.DEBUG, "download New Cases Started");
}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
    Log.d(AppController.DEBUG , "user id in the get cases link.." + userid);
    String url = AppController.ApiUrl + "GetCases?UserName="+ userid +"&stat="+state;
    Log.d(AppController.DEBUG_LINK,url);
try {
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("TEST", String.valueOf(response.length()));
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                Log.d("TEST","downloading data" );
                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray specs = object.getJSONArray("Spe");
                ArrayList<Specialities> spe = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < specs.length(); j++) {
                    Log.d("TEST",specs.getJSONObject(j).getString("SName") );
                    spe.add(new Specialities(null, specs.getJSONObject(j).getString("SName")));
                }
                Case ca = new Case(object.getString("ID")
                        , object.getString("Serial")
                        , object.getString("Name")
                        , object.getString("gender")
                        , object.getString("Age")
                        , object.getString("NatioanlityID")
                        , object.getString("HealthProblem")
                        , object.getString("CityID")
                        , object.getString("Problem")
                        , object.getString("Date")
                        , object.getString("Status")
                        , spe);

                Log.d("TEST",ca.toString());

                cases.add(ca);
                spe.clear();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Log.d(AppController.DEBUG , volleyError.toString());

    }
});
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        0,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
MySingleton.getmInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);

}catch (Exception e){
Log.d(AppController.DEBUG,"error in the asynctask in the  new cases freagment... ");
Log.d(AppController.DEBUG ,e.toString());
}
    Log.d(AppController.DEBUG, "Cases size ::" + cases.size());
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean bool) {
    super.onPostExecute(bool);

/*    if(listener != null){
        listener.getCases(cases);
    }*/
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 //   Log.d(AppController.DEBUG, "new Cases Downloaded...");


}
```

}
`
(I'm sure that the adapter and recycler view code is correct because I could use the same code now but when I came to test it again it did not work anymore and I can't remember if I changed some thing in it or not - I think not)..

this is my onViewCreate Method .

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctor_new_cases_fragment,container,false);
    Log.d(AppController.DEBUG_SHARED,"userID in the new case activity ..." + userID);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(AppController.PREFERENCES_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    userID = prefs.getString(DoctorProfileSubmitActivity.Shared_userid,null) ;
    downloadingNewCases tast  = new downloadingNewCases(userID ,"");
    tast.execute();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclervew_new_cases);
    adapter = new CasesAdapter(view.getContext(), cases);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null){
        parent.removeView(view);
    }
    return view;
}
```

and finally the Array list is declared as an instance variable of the class (the class extends Fragment + it is a fragment that I'm using in my view pager as a tab layout for my tabbed Activity .)
here's the ArrayList declaration

```
private final ArrayList<Case> cases = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Are you saying that cases is null and your adapter shows nothing?

Comment: Why are you trying to put volley inside an Asynctask?

Comment: @cricket_007 is that contains a problem ? 

i thought it is better to implement it in AsyncTask so i don't have to execute that kind of stuff on the UI thread + i can add my progress bar later too 

please if there is a better way tell me + tell what's wrong with this implementation

Comment: Volley doesn't execute on the UI thread. And you can put a progress dialog with Volley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys it was not worth it to add a question on the site right away 
i fixed the problem . (it appears that my problem was here)

```
Case ca = new Case(object.getString("ID")
                        , object.getString("Serial")
                        , object.getString("Name")
                        , object.getString("gender")
                        , object.getString("Age")
                        , object.getString("NatioanlityID")
                        , object.getString("HealthProblem")
                        , object.getString("CityID")
                        , object.getString("Problem")
                        , object.getString("Date")
                        , object.getString("Status")
                        , spe);
```

i accidentally changed object.getString("Gender") to object.getString("gender")
which caused me a JSONException .

i fixed that and everything is working again .

thanks for your help and i'm sorry if i rushed to ask the question without a proper debugging session first .

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you can print the data every step of the way, the problem is probably not related to your data. The problem might be your Arraylist of case And your CaseAdapter.

Let's try a simple test, instead of filling your adapter with case objects, create a new ArrayList of string and fill it with object.getString("name") in your on response. Then change your oncreateview to display this list of names using a normal string arrayadapter.

If you can successfully display the names, the it means the bug is in your case and caseadapter, you would have to show more code for us to help.